# rsync so that files in source and destination directory are the same

Tags: rsync

I am trying to do an rysnc which would cause files in the destination directory that are not in the source directory to be deleted.  As a result there would be the same number of files in the source and destination directories.  Based on google searches and other stack overflow inquiries I tried the following command:

```
rsync -avz -e -d  /home/web/dataprocess/testwind/*.dbf -d /home/web/newcheck/ --delete
```

While this did rsync over the files from the source directory that were dbf files, it did not delete the extraneous *.dbf files that are not present in the source directory like people said it would.  How can I get this to delete the extra *dbf file in the destination directory that is not in the source directory?

Answer (score 1):

The reason your command doesn't work is stated in the `rsync` man page:

> ```
> --delete
>     This tells rsync to delete extraneous files from the receiving side
>     (ones that aren't on the sending side), but only for the directories
>     that are being synchronized. You must have asked rsync to send the whole
>     directory (e.g. dir or dir/) without using a wildcard for the
>     directory's contents (e.g. dir/*) since the wildcard is expanded by
>     the shell and rsync thus gets a request to transfer individual files,
>     not the files' parent directory. Files that are excluded from the
>     transfer are also excluded from being deleted unless you use the
>     --delete-excluded option or mark the rules as only matching on the
>     sending side (see the include/exclude modifiers in the FILTER RULES
>     section).
> ```

However, using rsync filters to protect non-dbf files from deletion, we can use this command to accomplish your task:

```
rsync -avz -e -d src/ -d dest/ --delete --filter="R *.dbf" --filter="P **"
```

Comment: The command above didn't work on my machine but
rsync -avz -e -d . -d ../dst/ --delete --filter="+ *.dbf" --filter="- **"

did, what do the R and P mean? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

This should work and also properly creates subdirectories copying .dbfs (and deleting .dbfs without matches.)

```
rsync -avz -e -d /home/web/dataprocess/testwind -d /home/web/newcheck/ --delete --filter="+ */" --filter="+ *.dbf" --filter="- *"
```

Each file is passed through the filters in order, so the filters mean "Keep subdirectories, keep *.dbfs, and ignore everything else." (If you change the order of the filter arguments the result is probably incorrect. It's also not possible to pass multiple filters using one --filter, hence why the command looks a little redundant.)

When running this, you'll occasionally see a warning message "Cannot delete non-empty directory: *some directory*" if there is a directory in the destination that is *not* on the source and that directory contains at least one file that is not a .dbf. This warning can be safely ignored.