# When using `find ..` in rsync, rsync's --delete option is not working

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rsync

I'm using

`` rsync -avh --progress --delete `find /path/to/files -type f -printf "%p\n" | sort -rn | head -n 5` /path/to/backup/ ``

to backup the newest 5 files. The `--delete` option is supposed to delete the files in the destination folder, if they are not within the 5 files which find outputs. Unfortunately the `--delete` option is not working. How to get it working or how to do what I do differently?

Comment: RTFM. This behavior is described in documentation of rsync.

Comment: Can't find anything. And BTW, a well rated comment and I agree: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67539/how-to-rsync-only-new-files "Man pages suck (that's right I went there)"

Comment: Duplicate: [rsync so that files in source and destination directory are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37014926/3776858)